# multisig add button not appearing on polkadotJS apps after adding the pallet

Tags: polkadot-js, multisig

Here is my config setup for pallet_multisig:

```rs
parameter_types! {
    pub const DepositBase:u128 = 500;
    pub const DepositFactor:u32 = 50;
    pub const MaxSignatories:u16 = 5;
}

impl pallet_multisig::Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
    type Call = Call;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type DepositBase = DepositBase;
    type DepositFactor = DepositFactor;
    type MaxSignatories = MaxSignatories;
    type WeightInfo = ();
}
```

Here is my `construct_runtime`:

```rs
construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Runtime where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic
    {
        System: frame_system,
        RandomnessCollectiveFlip: pallet_randomness_collective_flip,
        Timestamp: pallet_timestamp,
        Aura: pallet_aura,
        Grandpa: pallet_grandpa,
        Balances: pallet_balances,
        TransactionPayment: pallet_transaction_payment,
        Sudo: pallet_sudo,
        // Include the custom logic from the pallet-template in the runtime.
        TemplateModule: pallet_template,
        PalletMultisig: pallet_multisig,
        PalletUtility: pallet_utility
    }
);
```

However when I build this, you can see the "+ multisig" button is greyed out:

[image]

What am I missing to properly configure the multisig pallet to work with polkadotJS?

Comment: How did you add it?
Please add more details.

Comment: Pallet multisig in developers/extrinsic on polkadosjs client appears now but the button is still unavailable. I do the same as in the substrate document, adding pallet nicks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the identifier names in your `construct_runtime`:

From this:

```rs
PalletMultisig: pallet_multisig,
PalletUtility: pallet_utility
```

To this:

```rs
Multisig: pallet_multisig,
Utility: pallet_utility
```

re-build and see if it works